# How to create or modify actions in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I do not find any way in order to modify the behaviour of the existing methods in rails_admin. I am using rails 3.2 and integrated with PostgreSql.

I want to modify the behaviour of one of my method during the edit. I have a model of shipment_quotes and model has a charges column, by default this field is blank and I want if admin add any amount in this field then after submitting the form a mail will be shoot to particular user.

But I have not found any way to modify the admin methods.

Also I want to create new actions for particular model.

Please help me I really fed up with this. After so much googling I do not find any thing relevant.

Any help will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Rails Admin wouldn't do this for you.  You might as well create a callback method for shipment_quotes after create.  I think something like this would help

```
class ShipmentModel < ActiveRecord::Base 
  after_create :verify_charges

  private     

  def verify_charges
    if !charges.blank?
      # Then shoot an email
    end
  end
end
```

Rails admin would then just handle your CRUD.